# Scenes vs. View Layers - What's the Difference?

Tags: scene, viewlayers

I'm still having a hard time understanding the difference between Scene and View Layers.  Would anyone mind explaining the difference, and what are the use case scenarios for one over the other?

Which one is best for compositing?

I would also love to know what are the key differences between New, Copy Settings, and Blank, when creating a new Scene or View Layer.

Comment: View Layers are supposed to be combined (like layers), while scenes are supposed to be separated - if the project is an animation, the scenes represent different time ranges (like scenes in a movie).

Comment: Note that due to how most addons are made in Blender, using addons and using multiple scenes in a file might result in funky behaviour since most addon properties are stored at scene level and most addons don't check if there are multiple scenes in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View Layers** are mostly used for the *Compositor*, they allow you, for each layer, to vary the visibility settings of the collections in order to assign an effect to a specific collection only, for example you'll be able to blur a collection while the others will remain unaffected.

*New* creates a new view layer with all the collections visible, *Copy Settings* creates a copy of your current view layer, with the exact same visibility settings, *Blank* creates a view layer with all the visibilities disabled.

As for the **Scenes**, they allow you to create a kind a of second file in your current blend, either linked or not linked to your current scene. I guess the reasons are many, like testing different settings for the same 3D scene, or being able to quickly switch from a scene to another.

*New* creates a brand new empty scene. *Copy Settings* creates a brand new scene with no objects but it keeps the settings of your current scene. *Linked Copy* will create a copy of your current scene with all the objects linked (but you can still unlink with *Object > Relations > Make Local > Object & Data*). *Full Copy* will create a copy of your current scene but the objects are unlinked (but you can still link objects if necessary).

Comment: One reason for a new scene within a file could be for example that it is not possible to put a scene strip into the video sequence editor within the same scene. You can only put strips from other scenes into the sequencer.

Comment: Oh yes, good idea, as long as you remember that you have created another scene within your file I guess

Comment: @moonboots thank you for this. I've had all these disparate bits of knowledge about Scenes and View Layers but couldn't put it all together in one cohesive context.  Your explanation is concise and total, and now so is my understanding ;)

Comment: Well now that is interesting @GordonBrinkmann, I'll have to look into the Sequence Editor sometime.  I've dabbled and was so frustrated I just gave up.  No doubt this came from my 25 years of editing (Avid, FCP, Premiere, etc) and my neural pathways that are just too stubborn to be broken!